# Integrating cocos2d in an existing app - OR - where does the white rectangle come from?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a "normal" app - initially without cocos2d. Now I need cocos2d in this app. So I added all the frameworks that are included when creating a cocos2d app and just copied the cocos2d group from another project by dragging it to my project.

For the init for cocos2d I get the application's window in an ivar of the ViewController which runs the init.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;


- (void) setupMyVC;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize window;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [self setupMyVC];
}

- (void) setupMyVC
{
    //get the mainWindow for the CC_DIRECTOR_INIT() 
    MyAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.window = mainDelegate.mainWindow;




    // CC_DIRECTOR_INIT()
    //
    // 1. Initializes an EAGLView with 0-bit depth format, and RGB565 render buffer
    // 2. EAGLView multiple touches: disabled
    // 3. creates a UIWindow, and assign it to the "window" var (it must already be declared)
    // 4. Parents EAGLView to the newly created window
    // 5. Creates Display Link Director
    // 5a. If it fails, it will use an NSTimer director
    // 6. It will try to run at 60 FPS
    // 7. Display FPS: NO
    // 8. Device orientation: Portrait
    // 9. Connects the director to the EAGLView
    //
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();

    // Obtain the shared director in order to...
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Sets landscape mode
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

    // Turn on display FPS
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];

    // Turn on multiple touches
    EAGLView *view = [director openGLView];
    [view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];    


    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [RecScene scene]];
}


@end
```

The code works - EXCEPT THAT I GET A WHITE RECTANGLE in the lower left corner (about 5 x 20 large). This rectangle is on top of every sprite I add.

Is that OK, just to drag the cocos2d Group into my app + adding the required frameworks to integrate cocos2d?

Is there something missing?

Or where does the rectangle come from?

Tanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could indicate that you forgot to add the file fps_images.png to your project's resources. In the lower left corner cocos2d displays the current framerate if enabled. Since you have it enabled with

```
[director setDisplayFPS:YES];
```

I strongly assume that this is your problem. Either turn of the FPS display or add the fps_images.png to your project's resources.

Comment: YES! That was it. Since there seems to be no other way to incorporate cocos2d into an existing app except of dragging it from an existing app into my own - I must have lost this one png.

Thanks a lot! Now it works fine!

ps but I don't understand really how this works - since it looked as if there is TOO MUCH there (the white rectangle) and not anything missing???